# Issue with CSS specificity(?)

Tags: html, css

I'm a complete CSS novice -- my background is back-end development. So please forgive the ignorance in advance.

I'm attempting to learn a bit more about the application (or.. practical use) of CSS.

Given the following CSS:

```
.input-size {
    height: 25px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why the following line of HTML in a WordPress page produces odd results:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="input-size">
```

I believe the issue has to do with specificity, but I am unsure on how to give a heavier weight to the style above.

The following image is what I expect:

[image: http://imgur.com/Vez8WlQ.jpg]

Notice the spacing between the bottom of the element and the canvas below.

However, when I apply the style to a textbox, I get the following:

[image]

There appears to be about a 25 pixel padding at the bottom, but that is not specified in the style posted above.

Any advice on moving forward would be appreciated. I'm, unfortunately, unsure of how to proceed with figuring out what could be causing the issue.

Thank you!

Comment: By "textbox" do you mean input or textarea?

Comment: Best way to get a fast answer is to copy your relevant html and css into http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/ and then post the link

Comment: Show us your relevant HTML + CSS  (that's not enough to help you at the moment)

Comment: The two answers (so far) are *stabs in the dark*.  There is not enough information in your question to answer it.  Keep in mind that MOST WordPress sites load thousands of lines of CSS.  There is *almost certainly* another style getting picked up (in your second screenshot).  You really need to inspect the **rules** - so using your inspector, look at the css rules being applied, and trace down through them - you'll almost certainly find it's inheriting some rule from somewhere else.  When you find that, if you can't solve the issue, then bring *that code* to your question.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for taking a stab -- it was the margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct, however you do not have padding defined in your new class. What is most likely happening is that padding is defined for `input` and it just inheriting the properties from the default style. Since you have it inspected - trace the margin rule.

Comment: why giving answers when there isn't enough info from the OP ?

Comment: Perfect -- thank you. Thanks to everyone else who took a stab at it as well. I now see how to trace the styles that are applied to the element in Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, try specifying

```
padding : 0;
```

So it would be:

```
.input-size {
    height: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: why giving answer when there isn't enough info from the OP ?